# Unable to get a Windows 10 license key in Microsoft Azure For Education

Tags: azure

I am a professor at a university participating in the “Microsoft Azure For Education” program, and my current goal is to get a “Windows 10 Pro” license key for a new computer. However, I do not see any “Windows 10” entries in the Azure software list. Minimally filtered, the list contains only 28 items:

[Azure Software List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AJvW.png)

When getting access to Microsoft Azure, I confirmed my Academic Status by clicking on the link sent to my university email address, and that fact seems to be indicated in my Azure profile:

[Azure Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MBTV.png)

Moreover, Microsoft Azure kindly welcomed me as an educator:

[Azure Welcome Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwiWs.png)

I guess, my status is not academic enough. :) My local university support is just surprised. I sent a request to Microsoft Support, but they seem to be very busy. Are there any other ways to solve the problem?

P.S. I asked the same question at Stack Overflow, and was recommended to post it here. I hope I haven't broken the tradition.

Comment: Talk to the individual responsible for your Azure subscription.  If Windows 10 is not offered, there really isn't a question, that can be answered by anyone except that individual.

Comment: Thank you, @Ramhound. (I was just suspecting myself in doing something wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a responce from Microsoft Support. There was a problem with email address and subscription. Hopefully, the problem will now be solved promptly.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes; I suppose Microsoft Support representative would be the next person who could help other than somebody responsible for your Azure subscription itself.